# Using 4 tuples to find probability.

Tags: probability

Suppose a,b,c, and d follow $Uniform[-1,1]$. I need to find $P(ad-bc>0)$. I know so far that $P(a>0)=P(a<0)=1/2$ (same for b,c and d) and that $P(ad>0)=p(ad<0)=1/2$ (same for bc). Im having trouble writing the expression for $P(ad-bc>0)$. I tried using a joint pdf, but it got me nowhere. Im currently trying to thing of this problem as finding a 4-tuple with the given condition, but that's as far as I can go. Any suggestions or hints in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hint (preassuming that $a,b,c,d$ are independent):

Observe that the events $\{ad>bc\}$ and $\{bc>ad\}$ have the same probability on base of symmetry.

Comment: Considering $P(ad>bc)$, I came up with the expression

$P(bc<0|ad>0) + P(bc=0|ad>0) + something$

For the blank expression, I'm trying to express the case where $ad>0$ and $bc>0$ but $|ad|>|bc|$.

Comment: Do you agree that $P(ad>bc)=P(bc>ad)$ and $P(ad>bc)+P(bc>ad)=1$? From that you can conclude that $P(ad-bc>0)=P(ad>bc)=\frac12$.